# Never getting an Location (MvvmCross Location Plugin, Android)

Tags: android, gps, mvvmcross

```
edit: turns out it just takes waaay longer than the native implementation. :/
```

I'm trying to locate my position by using the mvvmcross location plugin.

Everything works fine as long as my device settings (Nexus 5) are set to "Energy saving", so no GPS will be used.
As soon as I set it to "High accuracy", I'll never get a GPS fix.

This happens regardless to MvxLocationAccuracy.
My current workaround is to check, whether MvxLocationAccuracy is set to "Coarse", and if so, set PowerRequirement to Power.Medium.
This will prevent Android from using GPS.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong? Why am I never getting an location, as soon as my device is using GPS?

I compared the mvvmcross plugin code to one of my native projects, which gets a high accuracy gps fix in a few seconds. Unfortunately I didn't find any errors.

Comment: Are your permissions for the mvx app the same as the other working app? Is the SDK compilation level the same?

Comment: hi Stuart! Weirdly it's just waaay slower than the native implementation. So it's not a Mvvmcross problem. And thanks for your framework!

Comment: Thank you for this question, it helped me. I had a similar situation in MvvmCross on an old S3, where it did not seem to ever return OnLocation.
I then noticed that it was "Searching for a GPS" forever, once I forced GPS off I go a wifi location very quickly.